# How can a files with tilde be visible in Windows but not on linux?

Tags: linux

I accidentally created three files on a share on my NAS (running on linux). The files were created in folder `\home\abc` by a bash script running on the NAS but - strangely - they do not show up when listing the contents of `abc` using `ls -la \home\abc`. `abc` is also a share accessible from my Windows PC and there the files show as `BSPC07~P.LOG`, `BSPC07~T.LOG` and `BXDHDK~E.LOG` in windows explorer.

Never seen anything like this before. How is it possible that a file that was created on a linux machine using a bash script is invisible for that machine but visible from a Windows machine?

Some more info, in case it case it is relevant: the files came into being by something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE="$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)"
FILE="/home/abc/backup_NAS-$DATE.log"
echo "$(date) Starting backup ..." >> $FILE
```

Note the colon in the definition of the date variable. This didn't work as expected. Running this script did create a file with the date and the "starting backup" message, but the file name did look anything like `backup_NAS-$DATE.log`  but as shown above. And the files were only visible on windows.

I would like to delete these files but I have only read permission when accessing them from the windows share (even after running `chmod +R 0777 /home/abc`) so I can't delete them from there and I can't delete them via SSH on the NAS because they are invisible there...

Comment: Looks like the names are the "8.3" names for your files. Possibly Windows not liking the colon on the full name. But on Linux they would have the name created by the script.

Comment: On Linux they don't seem to exist. `ls -la` does not list any of them. It's weird.